# Bootstrap navbar active class not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the active class to work with my Bootstrap navbar but it's not working (I'm assuming because I've made too many CSS changes to the nav class).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <link href="css/base.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<style>
    #nav {
      white-space: nowrap;
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-bottom:10px;
      display: inline;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      border-bottom: thin solid #000099;
      padding-bottom: 4px;
      text-align: center;   
    }
    #nav ul {
      list-style: none;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      padding: 0; 
    }
    #nav li {
      display: inline-block
    }
    #nav li a {
      display: block;
      padding: 8px 15px;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #424245;
      border-right: 1px solid #ccc; 
    }
    #nav li:last-child a {
      border-right:none; 
    }

</style>
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Find It Myself</a></li>
        <li><a href="ask_the_community.html">Ask The Community</a></li>
        <li><a href="get_help.html">Get Help</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGbEgz). The active class is doing nothing. On top of that I'd like to make the active class to look like this:

[image: navbar]

Blue bar below instead of the standard darker-gray background that Bootstrap has. I'd settle for just the dark gray background but would like suggestions for how to accomplish the blue bar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve your desired effect by modifying your CSS and creating your own `active` class (below are just the changes to your CSS):

```
#nav {
/* removed bottom border form nav */
}
#nav ul {
  /* changed to inline block and put border from #nav here */
  display: block;
  border-bottom: thin solid #000099;
}
#nav li.active {
  /* created active class for your li elements */
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000099;
}
```

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmNyVW)

Comment: That's close. The mock-up provided by the OP has the bottom border more equal to the width of the text. Though I have no idea of the blue bar should always be the width of the text or a standardized fixed width.

Comment: Yeah, it's close enough that I can take the it the rest of the way, thanks JRulle. 

The navbar is for mobile so it length of text was actually perfect.

Comment: Here is a slightly adjusted version with the bar the same width as the text:  [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoQGxV) -- I mainly just changed which elements of your existing nav had which properties (i.e. moved the `border-right` from the `a` to the parent `li` and styled the `li.active a` to have the thick `border-bottom` css) -- you may still want to tweak the values a little bit but this should be a good starting point

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a CSS style to the `<li>` with the active class.

For example:

```
#nav ul li.active {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

This works in your codepen.

Comment: Granted, this just turns the background red to show you it works. You'll have to change the actual styles you need to accomplish the thick bottom border you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend this but nothing worked for me. I tried this with JS but when page refreshed, its gone. CSS also didn't work. Try everything , if nothing works, try this.

```
<div class="hidden" id="toMakeThisActive">home</div>
```

Place this in your each page.Change name "home" to your relative page.

```
 <li class="" id="home"><a href="link">Home</a></li>
```

Set same id for menu as the name to the relative page. Here "home".

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var id = $('html #toMakeThisActive').text();
    $('#'+id).attr('class','active');
  });
```

Add this code in your page. this will sure work. :)

(When page refresh according to menu and this is not the best way to do this. But it works.)